# Integrating Bootstrap carousel in WordPress without plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I have integrated the bootstrap carousel into my wordpress. Slides will be taken from pages, there will be a page called carousel and it will have subpages where post-thumbnails will be taken.
I'm still not very good at cms wordpress
someone help me please
Below is my code:

```
                    <div class="direction-carousel">
                        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                          </ol>
                          <div class="carousel-inner">
                          
                              <?php 
                              $args = array( [
                                'hierarchical' => 1,
                                'child_of'     => 5,
                                'parent'       => -1,
                                'post_type'    => 'page',
                                'post_status'  => 'publish',
                            ] );
                              $pages = get_pages( $args );
                            foreach( $pages as $post ){
                                setup_postdata( $post );
                                ?>
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('direction-carousel', '') ?>
                              <img class="d-block w-100" src="" alt="Первый слайд">
                            </div>

                         <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                         <?php 
                              $args = array( [
                                'hierarchical' => 1,
                                'child_of'     => 5,
                                'parent'       => -1,
                                'post_type'    => 'page',
                                'post_status'  => 'publish',
                            ] );
                              $pages = get_pages( $args );
                            foreach( $pages as $post ){
                                setup_postdata( $post );
                                ?>

                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('direction-carousel', '') ?>
                              
                            </div>


                             <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                          </a>
                          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                          </a>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I sort of figured out the code, but for some reason an error pops up: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token ":"

```
<?php
                    $i = 0;
                    $pages = get_pages([
                      'hierarchical' => 1,
                      'child_of'     => 5,
                      'parent'       => -1,
                      'post_type'    => 'page',
                      'post_status'  => 'publish',
                    ]);?>
                    <div class="direction-carousel">
                    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        
                          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                          
                          <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($pages); ++$i):
                          
                          ?>
                          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="<?= $i;?>"<?=($i==0 ? ' class="active"' : '');?>></li>
                          <?php endfor; 
                          
                          $i = 0;
                          ?>
                        </ol>
                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <?php
                          foreach( $pages as $post ):
                            setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                          <div class="carousel-item<?=($i == 0 : ' active' : '');?>">
                            
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('direction-carousel', '') ?>
                          </div>
                          <?php
                            ++$i;
                          endforeach;
                          wp_reset_postdata();
                          ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not post answers to your own questions unless they fix your specific problem. Edit your question **with** this code. What line does it tell you the syntax error is happening? Generally it's because you are missing a closing `)` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  <?php
                    $i = 0;
                    $pages = get_pages([
                      'hierarchical' => 1,
                      'child_of'     => 5,
                      'parent'       => -1,
                      'post_type'    => 'page',
                      'post_status'  => 'publish',
                    ]);?>
                    <div class="direction-carousel">
                    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        
                          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                          
                          <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($pages); ++$i):
                          
                          ?>
                          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="<?= $i;?>"<?=($i==0 ? ' class="active"' : '');?>></li>
                          <?php endfor; 
                          
                          $i = 0;
                          ?>
                        </ol>
                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <?php
                          foreach( $pages as $post ):
                            setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                          <div class="carousel-item<?=($i == 0 ? ' active' : '');?>">
                            
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('direction-carousel', '') ?>
                          </div>
                          <?php
                            ++$i;
                          endforeach;
                          wp_reset_postdata();
                          ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: it helped, but the forward/back buttons don't work

Comment: Check developers console for errors

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:279 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
bootstrap.min.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
slick.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/copp10/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b/#carouselExampleIndicators:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

Comment: Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
/copp10/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b/#carouselExampleIndicators:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
/copp10/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b/#carouselExampleIndicators:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
/copp10/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b/favicon.ico:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Looks like it can't found slick.js
https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Here are the errors it gives in the console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBib2.png)

Comment: This is not an answer, please use comment section to add more information to the question.